# Is it possible to connect to an in-memory sqlite db in Read-Only mode?

Tags: c++, c, database, sqlite

I know that I can open multiple connections to an In-Memory sqlite database using `file:DB_NAME?mode=memory&cache=shared` in `sqlite3_open_v2()`.

I open 2 connections to an In-Memory database. One with the flags `SQLITE_OPEN_URI | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE | SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE` and another with `SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY | SQLITE_OPEN_URI`.

The problem is that sqlite lets me modify the database even when the connection is Read-Only.

Is there any way to make the connection Read-Only? Should I write my own VFS to accomplish it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY` flag affects how the database accesses any files and handles transactions.

In [shared-cache mode](http://www.sqlite.org/sharedcache.html), multiple connections appear as a single connection in the interface to the file system. Therefore, they share the file access/transaction settings.

To prevent a connection from starting any write transactions, use [PRAGMA query_only](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_query_only).

Comment: Great! Thank you for the explanation and the solution.